# Upload zip file in visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, attachment, zip

Can anyone tell me how to upload a zip file in visualforce page?
My use case is:
I have to upload a zip file which contains 10 pdf files and assign these 10 files to 10 contacts
For that how can I do?
Thanks in advance
Karthick

Answer (score 2):

APEX has no buildin zip- and unzip support so uploading the zip as a single attachment will give you a hard time to proceed.

But in Visualforce you can utilize a really great JavaScript tool called jszip http://stuk.github.io/jszip/

Using it you can unzip client side and upload the files at the right place.

There is an article with more details:

- http://andyinthecloud.com/2012/11/04/handling-office-files-and-zip-files-in-apex-part-1/
- http://andyinthecloud.com/2012/12/09/handling-office-files-and-zip-files-in-apex-part-2/

Comment: Hey @Uwe Heim,                                                                                                                 can you give me the sample code

Comment: Hy @Uwe Heim I need source code for this scenario

Comment: No I can't provide you code. But if you read to the article you'll have all information you need to write it.

Comment: I cant understand from the article you provided..Thats y am asking the code